# Taylor expansion in $p$-adic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, taylor-expansion, p-adic-number-theory

> Let  $f \in Z_p[X]$, then for $ x, y \in Z_p$, $\exists a \in Z_p$ s.t.  $f(y)=f(x)+(y-x)f'(x)+(y-x)^2a$.

Why is Taylor formula applicable to polynomial in $p$-adic integers $Z_p$? What condition does the remainder term have?

And can it be expanded further to higher order? But it seems strange if it can, since
$\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$ is not defined in $Z_p$ for $n\geq p$ as $n!$ is not invertable.

(I'm not 100% sure whether the formula is true, in fact I'm reading the following lemma in Serre's a course in arithmetic, and it suggest it's true. If anyone could proof specifically for $y=x+p^{n-k}z$ as below, then I will accept it as an answer.)[image]

Comment: $p$-adic numbers form a field of chracteristic $0$, not $p$. Hence $\frac{1}{n!}$ should be defined for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: @Pavel The OP is working in $\mathbb Z_p$ and not in $\mathbb Q_p$. $p$ is not invertible in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @PavelC $Q_p$ is a field but $Z_p$ is just a ring, an element $a$ is invertible iff p|a.

Comment: CYC, is this supposed to be an equality of polynomials in $y$? It cannot be... Or are you saying that for every $x,y$ in $\mathbb Z_p$, there is an $a \in \mathbb Z_p$ such that the equality holds? Or is $a$ a polynomial? You're missing some quantifiers

Comment: @BrunoJoyal $a$ is different with different $x,y$

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I see, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered partially myself (this is enough for me).

It is suffice to prove for $f=X^m$, and this could be done by induction on $m$ easily.